# Display Multiple Photos as Featured Image when mouse moves on to it post

Tags: plugins, images, post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I need to add some photos (3 or 4 photos) to the post thumbnail (featured image) and should be displayed image 1, 2, 3 & 4 when mouse moves on to the post thumbnail...How can I do that. Please help me...

Comment: Please code script which you have tried.

Comment: Actually I don't have any idea on how to do that... I need some help, I'm new to WordPress. I have a Basic CSS knowledge. Can you please, help me to do that??